# Concurrent Network User Limit for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: networking

What is the Concurrent Network User Limit for Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 and Ubuntu Server 18.04.2
In Windows 10 Pro it is 20 Users maximum. 
I want setup a File Server for a 50 Systems Network (Windows and Ubuntu clients mixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no software limit. Only hardware(RAM, bandwidth) limit. You can have as many concurrent connections as your server able to process.

Comment: Thanks LeonidMew..
Is it the same with the Ubuntu Desktop and Server versions ?!!

Comment: Yes, but desktop requires a little bit more memory

Comment: I am building a PC with 16 GB RAM with a Dual Giga LAN and all. I assume that will take care of it. Thanks a lot once again